# How to send asynchronous requests/responses through collaborating Channel Adapters without correlating data

Tags: java, tcp, spring-integration

## Summary

I'm using Spring Integration's [TCP & UDP Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html) to proxy TCP stream traffic through my application to an upstream server, and then proxy that server's response back through my application to the client. Although this is two-way communication, I need high-volume, asynchronous throughput, so I can't use Gateways. Instead, I am trying to use Collaborating Outbound and Inbound Channel Adapters as described in section 34.8.2.

## Integration Component Setup

**Request**

A `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` receives requests via a `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` on port 6060. It places these requests on a requests `QueueChannel`. Requests are picked up by a `TcpSendingMessageHandler`, which send the request over a client connection generated by a `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory`. This connection sends the request out of my application and to the upstream server.

**Response**

A `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` receives responses from the upstream server via the `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` connection.It places these responses on a responses `QueueChannel`. Responses are picked up by a `TcpSendingMessageHandler`, which attempts to send the response back to the client via the connection from the original `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory`. This final connection is what fails.

```
    @Bean
    public PollableChannel requestChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(1000);
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel replyChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(1000);
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(6060);
        serverFactory.setSerializer(new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer(2));
        serverFactory.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer(2));
        serverFactory.setSingleUse(false);
        return serverFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory clientFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("127.0.0.1", 6080);
        clientFactory.setSerializer(new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer(2));
        clientFactory.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer(2));
        clientFactory.setSingleUse(false);
        return clientFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundRequestAdapter() {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundRequestAdapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        inboundRequestAdapter.setConnectionFactory(serverFactory());
        inboundRequestAdapter.setOutputChannel(requestChannel());
        return inboundRequestAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "50", receiveTimeout = "5000"))
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundRequestAdapter() {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundRequestAdapter = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        outboundRequestAdapter.setConnectionFactory(clientFactory());
        return outboundRequestAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundReplyAdapter() {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundReplyAdapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        inboundReplyAdapter.setConnectionFactory(clientFactory());
        inboundReplyAdapter.setOutputChannel(replyChannel());
        return inboundReplyAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "replyChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "50", receiveTimeout = "5000"))
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundReplyAdapter() {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundReplyAdapter = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        outboundReplyAdapter.setConnectionFactory(serverFactory());
        return outboundReplyAdapter;
    }
```

## Actual Result

Error:

```
Unable to find outbound socket for GenericMessage
```

Full stack trace:

```
2019-02-01 14:10:55.315 ERROR 32553 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : Unable to find outbound socket for GenericMessage [payload=byte[297], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6080, ip_connectionId=localhost:6080:51339:a3f66802-b194-4564-99c7-f194e55ddb11, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=bc36ec21-e2ae-405e-afa9-c0ec2f2eff8d, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1549051855315}]
2019-02-01 14:10:55.319 ERROR 32553 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[297], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6080, ip_connectionId=localhost:6080:51339:a3f66802-b194-4564-99c7-f194e55ddb11, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=bc36ec21-e2ae-405e-afa9-c0ec2f2eff8d, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1549051855315}]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:143)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:390)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:329)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:274)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This makes sense. I'm aware that a `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` sets the `ip_connectionId` Message header field when it forwards a message. Since I don't have any correlation logic right now, the ID header from the first inbound Adapter is lost when the payload is proxied upstream, and the second inbound Adapter generates a new ID header.

As a result, when the reply gets back to the final outbound Adapter, the ID header doesn't match anything that the corresponding inbound Adapter knows about. So, it doesn't know which connection to use to send the response.

My question is this: is there any way to set a "default" connection, or augment the payload with correlating data without sending that upstream?

The issue is that my application must be a transparent proxy in regards to the upstream server. If I augment the payload at all with correlating data, the upstream server will reject it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to correlate request/replies without the data containing correlation information.

The `TcpOutboundGateway` can do it because the socket itself is used for the correlation; only one request can be outstanding on each socket at a time. The `CachingClientConnectionFactory` allows concurrency in the gateway by maintaining a pool of sockets.

One technique might be a custom client connection factory that maintains a one-to-one map between your server factory connections and outgoing connections. Then, when a reply is received, look up the corresponding server factory connection to which to send the reply. It would just need a couple of maps - server connection id to client connection, and client connection id to server connection id.

If you come up with a solution, consider contributing it back to the framework.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I may look into that, if we can't find another solution.

Could I also achieve high throughput using Gateways and TaskExecutors?

Comment: A gateway with a `CachingClientConnectionFactory` should provide reasonable performance, but for best performance a completely async solution such as the one I described would be better.

Comment: Gary, my first attempt at this has been to base my custom client factory off of the `CachingClientConnectionFactory`, since I see that it overrides the `onMessage()` method in its inner class. Then, my strategy would be to change the logic of choosing the connection to use. `CachingClientConnectionFactory` just hands the message off to the next cached connection that is available, where instead I would want to hand it off to the appropriately mapped connection for the message's connection ID.

Comment: Does that seem like a good approach? Or could it be done more simply by just implementing `TcpListener` in my custom factory? I'm not sure if I need everything else from `CachingClientConnectionFactory`, including its inner class.

Comment: I think you just need a simple pair of `ConcurrentHashMap`s -  `inboundCID:outboundCID` and `outboundCID:inboundCID`.

Comment: Ok. In that case, what would be your recommendation on how to intercept the message as it passes through my connection factory? Just implement `TcpListener` and override `onMessage()`?

Comment: You just need a header-enricher in each direction to replace the connection id with the associated one - inbound - look up the outbound, if not found, or closed, open a new one and add it to the maps; in the return direction, if there is none found, it's an error condition.

Comment: You can also manage the maps with an `ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionEvent>` (or `@EventListener`), reacting to open and close events.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have an opinion on how to organize those different components? I'm thinking the custom conn. factory would maintain both maps and override `getConnection()` to return the correlated connection. Would it work to also declare the ApplicationListener or header-enrichers in that custom class too? 

Just thinking a single class would keep the feature/PR as simple possible to use.

Comment: You don't need to override anything. I would suggest a single stand-alone class/bean that listens to the events and gets a reference to the outbound factory. so it can get a connection when a new one is needed. Add two methods (one for each direction). The header enrichers can then use a SpEL  expression to call one or the other method to get the new value for the connection id (with override set to true).

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help so far. We've successfully set up the response header enricher with a SpEL expression to return messages back to the client. 

Now we're adding the request header enricher, where we need to create a new connection for the client connection factory based upon a new inbound connection to our server factory. We know how to add the header enricher, but how do we instruct the `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` to stand up a new connection? The `buildNewConnection` method looks like what we need, but it is protected.

Comment: The admins here don't like long commentary on questions/answers and it will not be easy to fit my suggestion into a comment. I suggest you close out this one, and start a new question. It can be brief; just add a link to this one.

Comment: Right, I tried to open the conversation in chat but don't have enough reputation. Anyways, here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404438/programmatically-create-multiple-connections-for-tcpnetclientconnectionfactory